# Check if a file is writable before writing to it

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script which will check if a file is writable before writing to it,

Making sure the script doesn't exit prematurely.

I've gotten this far

```
$meta =stream_get_meta_data($file);
while(!is_writable($meta['uri'])){
  sleep(rand(0,3));
  $meta=stream_get_meta_data($file);
  echo("sleeping\n");
}
$csv = fopen($file, 'a+')or die("can't open file");
```

When I test the script with $file open, it blocks on the sleeping part even after $file is closed.

I'm fairly new to PHP, so there might be a processing paradigm that i'm not aware of.

Any help would be very welcome.

EDIT : The reason I entered this into a while loop is to continually check if the file is open or not. Hence it should only exit the while loop once the file is finally writable.

The sleep is simply to replicate a person trying to open the file.

Answer (score 3):

its `is_writable ( string $filename )`

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_writable($meta['uri']) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I wanted to keep the while since i need it to be continually checked until the fie becomes writeable.

Answer (score 2):

```
is_writable(<your_file>)
```

This should do the trick?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

--

Also you can use

```
@fopen(<your_file>, 'a')
```

If this returns false, file is not writiable

Comment: @NullPoiиteя when is_writable returns false even on files that ARE writable the `@fopen` method ain't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Using [touch()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php):

```
if (touch($file_name) === FALSE) {
  throw new Exception('File not writable');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not be using a while loop just to check if the file is writable. Maybe change your code around a bit to something like this:

```
$meta =stream_get_meta_data($file);

if (is_writable($file)){
  sleep(rand(0,3));
  $meta=stream_get_meta_data($file);
  echo("sleeping\n");
}

$csv = fopen($file, 'a+')or die("can't open file");
```

However since I do not know what your main goal is you could do it like this:

```
$meta =stream_get_meta_data($file);

while(!is_writable($file)){
  sleep(rand(0,3));
  $meta=stream_get_meta_data($file);
  echo("sleeping\n");
}

$csv = fopen($file, 'a+')or die("can't open file");
```

Comment: thanks, i had tried the second option already, but even if $file is open, it quits the while loop, then exits in the fopen because the file is still open

Comment: its for that reason that i had to extract the meta data from the file first, and do the write check on that

Comment: Is this file something your opening and you just need to make sure you have exclusive access to it? If so maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php could help

Comment: By concept it seems like what I need, but I've just tried it and it doesn't seem to unlock either. My script is trying to write to a csv file opened in Excel (hence write locked). It should be continuously checked until that excel file is closed.