# PHP, check if the file is being written to/updated by PHP script?

Tags: php, file, url-rewriting

I have a script that re-writes a file every few hours. This file is inserted into end users html, via php include.

How can I check if my script, at this exact moment, is working (e.g. re-writing) the file when it is being called to user for display? Is it even an issue, in terms of what will happen if they access the file at the same time, what are the odds and will the user just have to wait untill the script is finished its work?

Thanks in advance!

**More on the subject...**

Is this a way forward using `file_put_contents` and `LOCK_EX`?

when script saves its data every now and then

```
file_put_contents($content,"text", LOCK_EX);
```

and when user opens the page

```
if (file_exists("text")) {

function include_file() {

    $file = fopen("text", "r");
    if (flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {
    include_file();
    }
    else {
    echo file_get_contents("text");
    }
}
 } else {
echo 'no such file';
}
```

Could anyone advice me on the syntax, is this a proper way to call `include_file()` after condition and how can I limit a number of such calls?

I guess this solution is also good, except same call to `include_file()`, would it even work?

```
function include_file() {

$time = time();
$file = filectime("text");

if ($file + 1 < $time) {
echo "good to read";
} else {
echo "have to wait";
include_file();
}

}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of, is to lock the file using the `flock()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: That would mean, the `include` would fail if no precautions are taken there.

Comment: Can we use the file operation fopen for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the file is currently being written, you can use filectime() function to get the actual time the file is being written.

You can get current timestamp on top of your script in a variable and whenever you need to access the file, you can compare the current timestamp with the filectime() of that file, if file creation time is latest then the scenario occured when you have to wait for that file to be written and you can log that in database or another file.

To prevent this scenario from happening, you can change the script which is writing the file so that, it first creates temporary file and once it's done you just replace (move or rename) the temporary file with original file, this action would require very less time compared to file writing and make the scenario occurrence very rare possibility.

Even if read and replace operation occurs simultaneously, the time the read script has to wait will be very less.

Comment: filectime() a usefull function that is!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the file, this might be an issue of concurrency. But you might solve that quite easy: before starting to write the file, you might create a kind of "lock file", i.e. if your file is named "incfile.php" you might create an "incfile.php.lock". Once you're doen with writing, you will remove this file.

On the include side, you can check for the existance of the "incfile.php.lock" and wait until it's disappeared, need some looping and sleeping in the unlikely case of a concurrent access.

Basically, you should consider another solution by just writing the data which is rendered in to that file to a database (locks etc are available) and render that in a module which then gets included in your page. Solutions like yours are hardly to maintain on the long run ...

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I add this answer because the other answers have no code.

```
function write_to_file(string $fp, string $string) : bool {
    $timestamp_before_fwrite = date("U");

    $stream = fopen($fp, "w");

    fwrite($stream, $string);
    while(is_resource($stream)) {
        fclose($stream);
    }

    $file_last_changed = filemtime($fp);

    if ($file_last_changed < $timestamp_before_fwrite) {
        //File not changed code
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is the function I use to write to file, it first gets the current timestamp before making changes to the file, and then I compare the timestamp to the last time the file was changed.