# How does wrinting and reading data at the same time work?

Tags: php, file-io

I got a simple general question on wrinting and retrieving data with PHP, something I cannot grasp the concept of.

If we have a website with a large number of visitors and with often updates, how do visitors access the pages that are currently beeing updated, should there be a conflict?

I asked somewhat connected question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160720/php-check-if-the-file-is-being-written-to-updated-by-php-script) and got some good responses (timestap, flock etc.), but on a larger scale, how does this work. Particulary interested in XML, for example [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/) uses XML for a database, and it can accomodate relatevely large websites easily. But how can you proof all the data to not to be broken while you are writing in data files and user accessing them at the very same time, and there could be many users and many editors?

Want to get the idea and technics in general, not just XML?

Answer (score -1):

I feel like the amount of time the physical files or data is actually being changed its very tiny, leaving a close to impossible condition of accessing the same data at the exact same time.

I would like to see someone accomplish a physical file written to and read from in the exact same millisecond...

Comment: so it is nothing to be concerned about? but in previous question that i refered to in text above, i was told that there will be a conflict if the file is being writing, for instance large file with entire contents replace

Comment: if the file is ENORMOUS, and your doing a complete content replace, then it might a long time. But getting up to that scale of a file is pretty ridiculous, do you foresee a situation where you'll have a file that large?

Even if the minute probability of having a file change that large (write) and someone accessing (read) that file at the exact same millisecond, the user might experience a 404 or something but there won't be any broken data. 

What traffics the read/write goes down to operation system levels of the server you are running, which it should have a file locking system or a queue